# Windows 10 keeps asking me to sign into my Android hotspot, which works fine elsewhere

Tags: windows-10, android, mobile-hotspot

I'm trying to connect my Windows 10 desktop computer to my Android 8 mobile hotspot for internet, but the connection keeps asking me to log into the network, so I can't get internet. Connecting my laptop to the mobile hotspot works just fine.

I have also tried Bluetooth tethering, which results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My desktop computer was connected to my router via LAN and it was the router asking me to log into my internet service provider. Disconnecting the LAN/Ethernet cable solved the issue and now the mobile hotspot is working fine.